# Asterisk Sip trunk though a PIX 501 firewall

Tags: firewall, voip, asterisk, cisco-pix

I'm using an asterisk VOIP server, and I'm able to make called though with my SIP client. The problem I get is one-way voice. I can hear the incoming voice but the caller can not hear me. I have no problems when using the X-Lite3 windows SIP client. I VOIP provider is broadvoice.

Could it be something in the firewall rules that I need to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you have nat? 
try to set canreinvite=no and nat=yes in sip.conf
please give me some sip.conf youve got

Comment: Both comments helped. I think the nat=yes was the fixing point of it

Answer (score 1):

There are several options you need to set correctly to make it work: localnet, nat, externip or externhost, qualify, canreinvite, etc.

See here: http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/9399